# Erro ao enviar e-mail com SendGrid no NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

Tenho a seguinte estrutura para enviar e-mails pelo `SendGrid`:

```
import mail from '@sendgrid/mail';

function send(email_data) {
  mail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  const message = {
    to: email_data.to,
    from: email_data.from,
    subject: email_data.subject,
    text: email_data.text,
  };

  return mail.send(message);
}

export default send;
```

Na minha Controller, eu chamo método `send` da seguinte maneira:

```
import mail from '../../services/sendgrid';

    const email_data = {
      to: 'myemail@hotmail.com',
      from: 'some_other_email@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Deposito realizado',
      text: 'Foi feito um deposito na sua conta ...',
    };
    
    mail.send(email_data);
```

Mas o seguinte erro é exibido pra mim:

`(node:7963) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: _sendgrid2.default.send is not a function`

Comment: Isso provavelmente vai ser erro de importação. Você exportou a função `send` como `default`, mas está tentando invoca-la como `mail.send`. Inclua no código como você importou esse módulo.

Comment: importei da seguinte maneira. coloquei acima

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, isso é um erro de importação.

Módulos exportam objetos em JavaScript, `default` é apenas uma das propriedades desse objeto. Quando você faz a importação do módulo, você pode escolher o que você quer importar:

```
// isso importa a propriedade default e a renomeia para metodo_1
import metodo_1 from "modulo"

// isso importa as demais propriedades via desestruturação
import { metodo_2, propriedade_1 } from "modulo"

// isso importa todas as propriedades e as colocam dentro do objeto tudo
// você pode acessa-los como tudo.default, tudo.metodo_2, tudo.propriedade_1
import * as tudo from "modulo"
```

Como `send` está sendo exportada como `default`, na hora de importa-la você deveria fazer

```
import send from '../../services/sendgrid';

const email_data = {
  to: 'myemail@hotmail.com',
  from: 'some_other_email@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Deposito realizado',
  text: 'Foi feito um deposito na sua conta ...',
};

send(email_data);
```

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda.